VBA - Way to recreate chart from excel in powerpoint i.e. the chart has to be created locally in powerpoint with the data from an excel chart
Basically, I should be able select the chart in excel, run the macro, the macro will open a new instance of PowerPoint, insert a new chart (with the same chart type as the one in excel) and update the ppt chart backend data with the data from the excel chart
Hope this was clear. Any support would be appreciated!
All content I found online only suggests code for copy-pasting with (a) link to excel or (b) an embedded chart
Apologies if I have missed an existing solution here.
Edit - Adding my sample code that can paste as well as embed...
Sub ExportChartExcelPPT()

Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Dim Chrt As ChartObject

Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
PPTApp.Visible = True
Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add
Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
Set Chrt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1)
Chrt.Copy

'Pastes Chart - But linked to source excel
PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste

'Pastes Embedded Chart - But includes full excel file and size
PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting")

End Sub

Welcome Nihal George! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

Please edit your question and add the code you have tried.

Please specify the reason why copy-pasting with (a) link to excel or (b) an embedded chart doesn't work on your project.

@taller (a) Link doesn't work because i want other users to be able to edit the chart if required (b) embed doesn't work because my source file is very large and will add to the ppt size

Just checking back in to see there if anyone has a potential solution.
